# "Vector3?" не содержит определения "x"

Tags: c#, unity3d, vector3

У меня есть класс :

```
public class VectorThree
{
    public Vector3? targetPosition;
    public VectorThree(Vector3 _targetPosition = default(Vector3))
    {
        if (_targetPosition == default(Vector3))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            targetPosition = _targetPosition;
        }
    }
    public bool MoveTowardsTargetPosition()
    {

        if (targetPosition.HasValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Почему если я хочу обратиться в методе к координате X,Y,Z (_s.targetPosition.x,_s.targetPosition.y,_s.targetPosition.z) Unity класса [Vector3](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html).

Выдаёт ошибку:`"Vector3?" не содержит определения "x", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "x", принимающий тип "Vector3?" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).`

код:

```
VectorThree _s = new VectorThree(queue[i]);
Vector3 vec = new Vector3((float)_s.targetPosition.x + r * Math.Cos(a), 0, (float)_s.targetPosition.z + r * Math.Sin(a));
```

Comment: убери  ты  тот  вопросительный  знак  после  vector3

Comment: @Slavik если вы не можете править вопрос это хорошо . Там не так просто стоит он . Сам вопрос можно прочитать чтоб понять

Comment: @Slavik И это  не знак вопроса , nullable тип во-первых и прямая цитата из ошибки . А во вторых не ты , а вы мы с тобой не пили на брудершафт .

Comment: я понимаю  что  это    за  тип,   поймы  ты   что   использовать  такое - может  быть  губительно для   производительности

Comment: ладно  бы  там  обыкновенная  программа  была,   но  игра ...

Comment: @Slavik предлагаю просто удалить бесполезные комментарии... они не помогают решению проблемы и только будут отвлекать пришедших с такой же проблемой от сути

Comment: лучшее   решение - удалить    знак  вопроса,    не  вводи  других  в  заблуждение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110738/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-slavik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что у вас `nullable` версия `Vector3`. К значению `nullable` класса надо обращаться так:

```
if(targetPosition.HasValue)
{
     var x = targetPosition.Value.x;
}
```